# Como limpar o cache de queries do MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, otimização

Como faço para limpar o cache de *queries*, armazenado pelo MySQL? Qual é o comando?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reset.html):

```
RESET QUERY CACHE;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/ResetQueryCache.sql).

Comment: Que resposta direta :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters você esperava umas preliminares antes?